# Adding own content to tabs UI on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got some problems with add my own content to new opened tab.

```
            add: function( event, ui ) {
            _CURRENT_TAB = $(ui.tab).attr('href');
            var tab_content = "TEST";
            $( ui.panel ).append( "<p>" + tab_content + "</p>" );
            $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
```

But I've callback on click function:

```
function tb(tab_title){
            return '#\\#tabs'+tab_title;
        };

$("#buuton").click(function(){
                $.post("open.php", { read: file },
                    function(data){
                        var read = data.read;
                        alert(read);
                        tab_content = read;
                    }, "json");

            $tabs.tabs( "add", "#tabs-" + tab_counter, "Lorem" );
            tab_counter++;
            $(tb(tab_title)).append(tab_content);
}
```

I'm using this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation. AJAX works - it gives me an value as I want. What I'm doing wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is with understanding how asynchronous transactions work. When you call $.post the javascript continues to execute before the .post is complete. This is the nature of asynchronous transactions. So you are basically calling your tb function before your .post function is finished setting the value of tab_content. Your logic should be something like this so that the tb() function is called inside the .post handler function:

```
$.post("open.php", { read: file }, function(data){
    var read = data.read;
    alert(read);
    tab_content = read;
    $tabs.tabs( "add", "#tabs-" + tab_counter, "Lorem" );
    tab_counter++;
    $(tb()).append(tb(tab_title));
}, "json");
```

Comment: It's still doesn't works. It's open a new tab but it don't put a new conent from tab_content. I've got an error: right code: $(tb(tab_title)).append(tab_content) but it still doesn'y works.

Comment: Is your tab_content var defined inside your tabs "add" function? If so then it is only local in scope to that function. If you are going to set the value of tab_content from your .post function then you need to move the var tab_content declaration to the main body of the script and remove "var" from in front of tab_content in your "add" function.